# How do I limit my character to follow a specific path on a map in a 2D game

Tags: c++

I have been working on a project, where I have a map background containing specific points. I've implemented moving functions for my character, and he can move north, south, east and west. However, there's only specific places on the map I want my character to be able to move. Other movements aren't valid and shouldn't register anything except minus a score point. Here's an attached image for reference:

[image]

I don't know how I should approach this though. I have the movement function in the form of:

```
void makeMove(string direction){
if (direction == "East"){
    moveEast();
    nCollarsFound++;
}
```

So far I've been able to come up with the idea of perhaps creating a location set, where I can assign the starting circle as x = 0, y = 0 and hard code each individual circle to be x += 1 and y += 1, however while I understand the theoretical aspect of this. I'm unsure of how I can approach this. If anyone can point me in the right direction or provide an explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How do you expect the character to actually move? You imply that it's invalid (and not allowed) for them to move outside one of these circles. And they can only move in rectangular directions. So, it seems that they should "hop" from one circle to the next. But how is it possible for them to reach the bottom-most circle which is not vertically or horizontally aligned with any of the other circles? Perhaps you need to represent the map locations as a graph with edges that define a valid path between locations.

Comment: What is a character and how exactly does the world fit into your implementation of movement? Is your Character just some arbitrary shape that gets handled like a single pixel? Or something more complex? Is your world just a rasterized image like you've attached? Or do you have an intermediate format (like [circle(215,360),circle(415,557),...])? You'll get wildly varying answers based on this information. But so far, I too would suggest a graph structure based on an intermediate format like @paddy.

Comment: @paddy So I've been given skeleton code which I'm supposed to work on. And in this regard, the specific movements are set I simply have to make the rules for the movement. One mistake from the map is the circle that's misaligned, all the circles are vertically/horizontally aligned and every pre defined movement does land on another circle. Representing it with graphs and edges does seem intuitive but I wonder if creating a set of points, and incrementing the x and y values and seeing if they overlap and land on the pre existing coordinates would work?

Comment: @TARN4T1ON The character is a pre made sprite, and the world is just a 2d image.

Comment: You haven't shown any useful skeleton code, and your descriptions are vague. If all the locations are rectangularly aligned, it should be trivial to scan for them in the image. If your "map" is just an image with "islands" of pixels representing a location, you can run a flood-fill algorithm and/or disjoint sets to identify them. Then for each island, if it's truly a circle, then computing the average of every pixel co-ordinate will find you the center of the circle.